# Vue: call a parent function from child with extra param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a table component which contains a child headers component injected into a slot:

```html
<AqTable>
      <template slot="headers">
        <AqTableHeader checkbox @checked="checkAll" />
        <AqTableHeader @click="sort('name')" text="Name" />
        <AqTableHeader @click="sort('dns')" text="DNS" />
        <AqTableHeader @click="sort('status')" text="Status" />
        <AqTableHeader @click="sort('last')" text="Last Seen" />
      </template>
</AqTable>
```

**AqTableHeader (only the relevant parts):**

```html
<template>
  <th :class="{small: checkbox}" v-on="$listeners">
    <AqCheckbox v-if="checkbox" v-model="checkAll" />
    <div class="flex" v-if="!checkbox">
      <span v-text="text"></span>
      <div class="sort" v-if="sort">
        <AqIcon icon="triangle-up" class="top" small v-if="isAsc"/>
        <AqIcon icon="triangle-down" class="bottom" small v-if="!isAsc"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </th>
</template>

<script>
import { AqIcon, AqCheckbox } from "comp/common";

export default {
  props: {
   ...
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isAsc: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

As you can see, when the user clicks the header component, he calls the sort method with a parameter he passes (`@click="sort('name')"`)
I also want to be able to pass the `isAsc` state from the child component.

Is there a way to use `$listeners` to intercept the click in the header component and call it with an extra parameter?

Comment: I don't think there is any way you would be able to do what you want if they define the click handler the way you define it above. If they, however, set the handler simply to a function reference, then you could get the field to sort on from elsewhere and pass whatever else you wanted. [Here is an example of what I mean](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZxdqgZ?editors=1010).

Comment: This seems complicated though. If you want the use to be able to define the sorting mechanism, maybe a property where they provide the sort method is more appropriate.

Comment: I guess you're right, I'll just pass a sort-field property, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using data attributes.

First, add `$event` param to `sort` method. this would be the event object for the click event.

```
<AqTableHeader @click="sort('name',$event)" text="Name" />
```

in AqTableHeader, add a data attributes for `isAsc`

```
<template>
    <th :class="{small: checkbox}" v-on="$listeners" :data-is-asc="isAsc">
        <!-- ... -->
    </th>
</template>
```

and in `sort` method, get `isAsc` using the event parameter

```
    sort(type,$event) {
        const isAsc = $event.target.dataset.isAsc;
        // ... other logic
    }
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but i'd rather have a cleaner solution that doesn't involve the user having to know how to get the sort direction.